# Update NULL fields with last recorded field that has the same ID - mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need to UPDATE null fields under the colucm "seller_name" with previously recorded seller
names that have the same "Product_ID" field. For example given the following table:

| seller_name | Product_ID |
| --- | --- |
| iYRO ig | 2185564723 |
| Mpiysusu | 2152514625 |
| iYRO ig | 2185564723 |
| oti | 1178042531 |
| **NULL** | 2152514625 |
| **NULL** | 2152514625 |
| Mpiysusuyi | 2152514625 |
| **NULL** | 2152514625 |
| ioKU | 1330811490 |
| Tsug | 595898812 |
| Tsug | 595898812 |
| **NULL** | 1178042531 |

The final output should be:

| seller_name | Product_ID |
| --- | --- |
| iYRO ig | 2185564723 |
| Mpiysusu | 2152514625 |
| iYRO ig | 2185564723 |
| oti | 1178042531 |
| **Mpiysusu** | 2152514625 |
| **Mpiysusu** | 2152514625 |
| Mpiysusuyi | 2152514625 |
| **Mpiysusuyi** | 2152514625 |
| ioKU | 1330811490 |
| Tsug | 595898812 |
| Tsug | 595898812 |
| **oti** | 1178042531 |

I'm new into SQL so any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: "...with previously recorded seller names..." -- How do you decide which row is the *previous* one? Remember that in relational tables rows do not have inherent ordering.

Comment: That's a good question. There is no more info about this so i suppose it has to do with the given order(?). I don't really know.

Comment: Then, the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the other values came from but if you just want to update the column with the null values you can try to do this.

```
Update mytable m Join (select seller_name, Product_ID from mytable 
group by Product_ID) k
on k.Product_ID = m.Product_ID
set m.seller_name = k.seller_name
where m.seller_name is null
```

Comment: i tried your solution but although the requested rows were found, they were not updated! @fonz

Comment: what version of mysql are you using? I edit my answer. I forgot to remove the where clause in the select query.

Comment: I'm using version 8.0. The new answer kinda did it. Actually 35 out of 39 null seller names changed.

Comment: I think the remaining null did not meet the conditions above. that's why the names of seller did not update

Comment: meaning the 4 remaining null has NULL values initially.